# Pandoc renders file to same folder. Can I change the destination folder?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, directory, markdown, pandoc

I want to use Pandoc to convert Markdown files to HTML files in a specific folder. How can I do this? By default, they are rendered to the same folder. I tried to use -o html/ but this does not seem to work.

See imgage below for example and Pandoc settings.

[image: img]

Comment: Pandoc is very conservative when writing files. It will only write files when told explicitly, and you'll have to give the full filename that you want to produce: `-o html/write-this-file.html`

Answer (score 4):

The `-o/--output` flag must include the path to the file, **including the file name**. Therefore you would need to do:

```
pandoc -o html/hello.html hello.md
```

As an alternative, you can use Pandoc's default of writing to standard output and redirect that to a location of your choice via a pipe (using `>` to write to a file). Perhaps something like this:

```
pandoc -t html hello.md > html/hello.html
```

However, you still need to specify the full path including the filename, so that doesn't provide any advantage over using the `-o/--ouput` flag. In fact, as no output filename was provided to Pandoc (which would contain a file extension and be used to determine the output format), you need to also specify the output format directly with the `-t/--to` option (although the default output format is `html` so maybe not).

Looking at the screenshot provided, it would appear that you are attempting to configure your text editor (vscode) so that whenever it calls Pandoc it will use a subdirectory. Unfortunately, Pandoc does not provide a flag for that. You would need to have vscode include the filename each time (maybe you could provide a template something like `-o html/{filename}.html` where vscode would replace `{filename}` with the actual filename each time the command it called). However, I'm not aware if vscode supports that sort of thing. If it does, you'll need to consult vscode's documentation to see what format is supported and what variable names are available. It not, then it may simply not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I use bash in the vscode terminal to run pandoc, and I have set up a function in a bash script to set pandoc arguments in my preferred way.

e.g.

```bash
md2htm() {
  NAME=$(basename --suffix=".md" "$1")
  OUTPUT=${2:-$WORKSPACE/Output/$NAME.html}
  pandoc "$1" -o "$OUTPUT" >/dev/null
```

Then I call this with `md2htm [input_file_path]`.

You could modify the OUTPUT to get the desired destination.

You should be able to do something similar in `.vscode/settings.json`. I haven't done that but I have set up `.vscode/launch.json` in a way that should be applicable to `settings.json`.

```json
"args": [
    "-o",
    "${workspaceFolder}/mapjs-example/index.html",
]
```

Note that you can also use variables to refer to other settings using: `${config:lua.debug.settings.system_root}`

Note that not all settings support this variable and I haven't worked out the pattern! So it might not work within the setting you want.

If it does work, you can have the desired output folder configured differently for each project, which is handy.